# Handling a null operator for a callback

Tags: dart

Does the Dart language have anything better to handle the potential of the callback being null than I have done here:

```
if(widget.onChanged!=null){
                   widget.onChanged!(value);
                 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case onChanged is of type Function, you can use

```
onChanged?.call(value);
```

This will only call the function if it is not undefined/null.